# Feed decoder input in transformers

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, nlp, transformer-model

Reading [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/transformer) on how to implement an Encoder/Decoder transformer I had some doubts on the training process. Specifically as reported by the original [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762) the decoder should iteratively use the last iteration output as input of the decoder. However the training step is implemented as

```
@tf.function(input_signature=train_step_signature)
def train_step(inp, tar):
  tar_inp = tar[:, :-1]
  tar_real = tar[:, 1:]

  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    predictions, _ = transformer([inp, tar_inp],
                                 training = True)
    loss = loss_function(tar_real, predictions)

  gradients = tape.gradient(loss, transformer.trainable_variables)
  optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, transformer.trainable_variables))
```

Where `tar_inp` is simply a tokenized sentence without the EOS token and `tar_real` is the same sentence shifted by one position.

However I would have expected the target input (the decoder input) to be iteratively concatenated by previous prediction (or in teacher-forced by incrementing by one ground truth token at a time).

Why is it not the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular example actually uses teacher-forcing, but instead of feeding one GT token at a time, it feeds the whole decoder input. However, because the decoder uses only autoregressive (i.e. right-to-left) attention, it can attend only to tokens `0...i-1` when generating the `i`'th token. Therefore, such training is equivalent to teacher-forcing one token at a time, but is much faster, because all these tokens are predicted in parallel.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So if I wanted to implement a non teacher-forcing method I would need to effectively run the training steps one by one and concatenating the prediction? Would I need to execute a `for` loop over the execution of the `transformer` (referring to the previous piece of code)?

Comment: Yes, you would need to code some kind of `for` loop. To speed up this loop, you could cache hidden states that have been already calculated on the previous steps.